# Expo react native facebook login - what to put as Facebook login redirect URL for facebookScheme?

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-login

Im reading the following on expo docs:

> Configuration in app.json / app.config.js
> Add the field facebookScheme with your Facebook login redirect URL scheme found on the Facebook Developer website under "4. Configure Your info.plist." It should look like "fb123456". If you do not do this, Facebook will not be able to redirect to your app after logging in.

I keep seeing that facebookScheme is same as CFBundleURLSchemes which is a string consisting of: 'fb'. That isnt a redirect URl. Do I need to add that and if so how do I know what it is in a expo managed app? When I log in into facebook Im getting an err on expo go app, that the hostname isnt found. Maybe its because of the facebookScheme?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same problem... a few days ago it works without facebookScheme key in my app.json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).